# How to trigger an event when clicked in PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, listener, preferencefragment

I use androidx. In the settings fragment, I want to create the "Preference" buttons and click on them to trigger some individual events.

How can I implement a click listener on a specific Preference?

Thats some my Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.graylight));

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.action_settings);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_settings_white_24dp);

        PreferenceManager preferenceManager = getPreferenceManager();
        PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();

        return view;
    }

}
```

And XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/setting_person"
        app:initialExpandedChildrenCount="0"
        app:key="profile_set">

        <Preference
            android:id="@+id/preference2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:key="button1"
            android:summary="@string/setting_person_data"
            android:title="@string/setting_person_reg"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_assignment" />
        <Preference
            android:key="button"
            android:summary="@string/setting_avatar"
            android:title="@string/setting_avatar_chg"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_wallpaper_black_24dp" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

As a result, I want to click on the trigger an event in MainActivity. But this is another question, now at least I should get a listen to the event, for example by calling Toast with the key of the button pressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much torment, the solution was found as follows: (for AndroidX)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

            Preference preferenceMap = findPreference("button");

            preferenceMap.setOnPreferenceClickListener(
                    new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                            getActivity().onBackPressed();
                            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).injectSetting("map");
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.graylight));

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.action_settings);
            toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_settings_white_24dp);

            return view;
        }

    }
```

and in XML androidx.preference is added to the element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/setting_person"
        app:initialExpandedChildrenCount="1"
        app:key="profile_set">

        <androidx.preference.Preference
            android:id="@+id/preference1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:key="button"
            android:summary="@string/setting_person_data"
            android:title="@string/setting_person_reg"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_assignment" />
        <androidx.preference.Preference
            android:id="@+id/preference2"
            android:key="button2"
            android:summary="@string/setting_avatar"
            android:title="@string/setting_avatar_chg"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_wallpaper_black_24dp" />
    </androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory>

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

And do not forget at build.gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
```

Maybe someone will need ))

Answer (score 8):

**Find** the preference, then **set a click listener on it**.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

        Preference preference = findPreference("button1");
        preference.setOnClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference p) {
                // Handle preference click
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please review the documentation on using Preferences:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/package-summary.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: i tried this but for `Preference preference = findPreference("button1");`  I see:  `type parameter t has incompatible upper bounds: Preference and Preference`

Comment: In MainActivity:   `Fragment fragmentPref = new SettingsFragment(); FragmentManager ft = getSupportFragmentManager(); ft.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainlayout, fragmentPref,"Preference").addToBackStack(null).commit();`

Comment: That doesn't help. This code goes in your PreferenceFragmentCompat class, not the activity.

Comment: All PreferenceFragmentCompat code is indicated in the top message

Comment: You code in the top message does not include the click listener handling that I suggested which you claim does not work.

Comment: I created a separate question where I put the code of the fragment: 

 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684399/why-am-i-getting-an-error-parameter-t-has-incompatible-upper-bounds-preferenc)