# Why am I getting an error?: parameter t has incompatible upper bounds: Preference and Preference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I can not solve the problem with the error:

```
incompatible types: no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds com.velocat.cmap.Preference,androidx.preference.Preference
        Preference preference = findPreference("button");
                                              ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends androidx.preference.Preference declared in method <T>findPreference(CharSequence)
```

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsFragmentActivity extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    Preference preference;
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting);

        Preference preference = findPreference("preference1");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        return view;
    }

}
```

part of **buld.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'

}
```

**xml/settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="preference1"
        android:title="test" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I re-read everything possible in the search, but did not find a solution to the problem.
Does anyone know how to get rid of this error?

I would be grateful for any clarification on this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you imported wrong **Preference**  it should be

```
import androidx.preference.Preference
```

as you are extending `androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat`  and as per [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)) it returns

```
androidx.preference.Preference
```

Answer (score 1):

just import these libraries instead

import androidx.preference.Preference;

import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;